# How to access attributes of XML tags

Tags: xml, r

How could I read out all the attributes of `<part` if I have a list like `list.db[[1]]` from the following example? And how I could select a node without child nodes?

```
require(XML)

txt = "<doc>
         <part name=\"abc\">
           <name>ABC</name>
           <type>XYZ</type>
           <cost>3.54</cost>
           <status>available</status>
         </part>
         <part>
           <name>ABC</name>
           <type>XYZ</type>
           <cost>3.54</cost>
           <status>available</status>
         </part>
       </doc>"

tree <- xmlTreeParse(txt, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
list.db <- getNodeSet(tree, "//part")
list.db[[1]][1:2]
xmlRoot(list.db[[1]])[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `xmlAttrs` function:

```
xmlAttrs(list.db[[1]])
# name 
#"abc"
```

Or you could use XPATH Syntax via `xpathSApply`:

```
xpathSApply(tree, "//part/@name")
# name 
#"abc"
```